# add a line of text above a matching pattern

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have bunch of .cpp files. say 
tes1.cpp

```
 example
//commented
 abc
 def
```

test2.cpp

```
efg
```

test3.cpp

```
def
efg
```

I need to write a script,

```
 find which file has abc pattern, 
  if found need to find if it has //commented pattern, 
    if it is found then find if //additional text,
        if not found then add a line of text //additional comment above //commented
```

output file should be,
test1.cpp

```
example
//additional comment
//commented
abc
def
```

i tried with

```
if grep -Erl '\babc\b' *; then
   if grep "//commented" ; then
   echo "Already updated"
   else
  sed '\/\/ commented /i\// additional comment' 
  fi
fi
```

but execution hangs. how do i do it?

edit:
editing the command

```
grep -Erl '\babc\b' * | xargs sed -i '/ commented /i \// additional comment'
```

but it does not check whether the file already had //additional comment pattern

Comment: So for `test2.cpp` and `test3.cpp` no change should be done?

Comment: @Inian yes.. test2.cpp and test3.cpp should not change because it does not have abc pattern

Comment: but test2.cpp has the `abc`.

Comment: @JamesBrown edited. but test2.cpp does not have //commented pattern

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS=OFS="\n"}/abc/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/\/\//)$i="//addtional comment\n" $i}1' file
 example
//addtional comment
//commented
 abc
 def
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    RS=""                                 # record changes at first empty line
    FS=OFS="\n"                           # field separator is a newline
}
/abc/ {                                   # if record has abc
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                    # iterate all fields
        if($i~/\/\//)                     # at line with comment
            $i="//addtional comment\n" $i # add the addition
}1' file                                  # print
```

It preceeds a line with `//` with the `//additional comment`. Feel free to tune the regex in the `if` to your liking. This script only processes one file at the time.

Answer (score 0):

sed:

```
grep -L ' additional comment' * | 
xargs grep -Erl '\babc\b' | 
xargs sed -i '/ commented /i \// additional comment'
```

This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri -e '/abc/{:a;i//additional comments\n//commented' \
 -e 'b};N;//{:b;\#//commented#{i//additional comments' \
 -e 'b};P;s/.*\n//;ba};N;//{\#^//additional comment#{p;d};P;s/[^\n]*\n//;bb};P;D' file
```

If a line contains `abc` insert the two lines of required text. Otherwise, read the next line and if this contains `abc`, check if first line began `//commented` and if so, insert the first line of required text and print the other two lines, else print the first line, remove it and then treat the line as if it were the first. Otherwise, check the third line for `abc` etc.